# Visualizing large amounts of spatial vector data using WebGL

Tags: openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I plan on doing an application that visualizes large 2d tiled images. The application needs to achieve the following:

1. Additive blending of layers, i.e. somehow setting the blend equation of WebGL to be additive: `gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD)`.
2. Colorization of black and white images (multiply by constant color, e.g. red. This would correspond to setting `gl.blendColor(1, 0, 0, 1);` and `gl.blendFunc(gl.CONSTANT_COLOR, gl.ONE);`).
3. Drawing of large amounts of simple vector data (mostly polygons).
4. Contrast/brightness/range of intensity manipulation

According to my research, the renderer should be WebGL based for these goals.
I did an initial prototype using Openlayers 3. I managed to implement everything except **(3)** using the `precompose` and `postcompose` hooks and a custom shader for the range of intensity manipulation. I saw, however, that polygon rendering using WebGL is not supported yet and I haven't seen a recent update on this issue/state of the development. My question is if there is a possibility/some starting point to implement this myself or if something like cesium would be a better match for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to the OpenLayers roadmap, but Cesium itself should be able to handle your requirements out of the box.  Here's some examples (with code) showing the features you are looking for

[Additive blending of layers](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Imagery%20Layers.html&label=Showcases)

[Polygons](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html&label=Showcases) This is GeoJSON but we also handle KML, TopoJSON, CMZL and have a [programattic API](http://cesiumjs.org/2015/02/02/Visualizing-Spatial-Data/).  We also handle a [diverse set of geometry](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Geometry%20and%20Appearances.html&label=Showcases)

[Imagery Adjustment](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Imagery%20Adjustment.html&label=Showcases)

If you decide to give Cesium a try, we have a very [active forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/cesium-dev) that can help you get started, so don't hesitate to post any questions you have. [cesiumjs.org](http://cesiumjs.org) also has plenty of additional info, help, and demos.

Comment: It indeed looks promising. Regarding the blending, I'm not sure if I got this correctly. In the example you mentioned, are the layers blended purely additively? Because what I need to do is basically set the blend equation to `GL_FUNC_ADD` and colorize the individual black and white layers by setting the `blendFunc` to `GL_CONSTANT_COLOR` with a `blendColor` of for example `(1, 0, 0, 1)`, i.e. red. Is this still possible?

Comment: As an example: one black and white layer should be colorized red, another green. Then the blending should simply add the channels so that the addition of two pixels works like this: (255, 0, 0) + (0, 255, 0) = (255, 255, 0). Is this possible out of the box or is there a possibilty to adjust the renderer accordingly (i.e., like I mentioned previously, by setting the blend equation before the layer is rendered).

Comment: The blending of layers is additive, but you also have to take alpha is also taken into account, so an opaque color will overwrite another opaque color.  Your example would more accurately be something like (1, 0, 0, 0.5) + (0, 1, 0, 0.5) = (1, 1, 0, 1).I recommend you check out the [Imagery Layers tutorial](http://cesiumjs.org/2013/01/04/Cesium-Imagery-Layers-Tutorial/) which should cover most of what you need.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter.  I wanted to add that it should be easy to test our your use case and if you run into any problems you'll get more eyeballs on your question via our forum than on stack overflow.